# Unable to write integer to a string

Tags: c++, string

Below is the code for converting integer to string,I am trying to not use C++ inbuilt functions for that but my code is not producing any output.

```
int main(){
int a;
string b;
cin>>a;
while(a){
    b+=(a%10);
    a/=10;
    }

cout<<b;
return 0;
}
```

**Input**-

```
789
```

**Expected Output-**

```
987
```

but I am not getting any answer.
P.S- I have used all the required header-files in the code.

Comment: *I have used all the required header-files in the code.* Then quite why the <censored> did you feel compelled to cut them off before posting your code *and* to type a notice to this effect? Just show it whole with the <censored> headers.

Comment: you need to convert `a%10` to string as well in order to concatenate it with `string b`. Since `a%10` would be a single digit, so converting it to a `char` and then adding it to `string b` would also work. For doing this, you could simply add character `'0'` on the rhs of `b+=(a%10)`.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: @n.m. I have not included header files because somewhere in stack overflow documentation ,it is written that only the minimal code is required to get the work done.And I included the P.S because to refrain some some users to add that I forgot to add header files,I know ,this is stupid but I tried to cover all the corner cases

Comment: "Minimal" doesn't mean "you should remove the headers", it means you should you should come up with minimal code that still exhibits the problem. Removing headers prevents code from doing anything, so please don't do that. Read about [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add an `int` to a `string` (or rather, you shouldn't in this case). You need [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert the int to a string so that the `+=` operator acts as concatenation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a;
    string b;
    cin>>a;
    while(a){
        b+=std::to_string(a%10);
        a/=10;
    }
    cout<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p3MdzpV6MjpJYJyv)

---

#### What was happening?

`std::string` has a [`operator+=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) that can allow for quick concatenation. You can concatenate another string **or** a character. Which version of concatenation is chosen via overload. When you tried `string += int` the `char` overload was selected (`int` converts to `char`) so random junk was appended to your string instead of what you intended.

Comment: @n.m. Upvoted. I will leave this answer as-is because it's overall safer for future visitors that may not understand the significance of `a%10` in making that work.

Comment: does using '0' with it ,type cast the whole of the statement into a string

Comment: @learner: You're still using an integer, but adding '0' to the result will guarantee that you get a value that is equivalent to the ASCII value for a digit between 0 and 9 (inclusive). The result is again converted to a `char` as before, except this time it's not a "junk" value, but exactly what you need.